# how to get only date from timestamp in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, logstash-file

I have date format 12/1/2020 12:08:27 AM, I want only date like **12/1/2020**. Is any way to get date in logstash? I have tried to find out the date but didn't get, What I want then I separated each term like **day,month, year**. But Actually I want complete date format as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you add the configuration you've tried so far?

Comment: finally I have got the solution. Let me share here that will help others as well         
 date {
        match =>["SMSDate", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"]
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_field =>{
            "date" => "%{+MM/dd/yyyy}"
        }
    }

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You should create an answer instead of commenting, that will better help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grok` instead of `date`. The `date` filter is for converting strings to timestamps *only*. Here's an example (using the field name from your comment).

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "SMSDate" => "^%{NUMBER:day}\/%{NUMBER:month}\/%{NUMBER:year}" }
  }
}
```

The approach in your own comment, which uses Logstash's date math on the `@timestamp` field, is also valid.